# Looking for dropdown on android webview that is working

Tags: android, android-layout, drop-down-menu, webview, android-webview

Native select and also smart select picker from framework 7 are shown but when I click on them nothing is opened.
Here is an example I have tried, I can see the drop down but when I click on it nothing is happened:

```
<select name="car">   
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="vw" selected="">Volkswagen</option>
  <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
  <option value="cadillac">Cadillac</option>
  <option value="nissan">Nissan</option>
  <option value="mazda">Mazda</option>
  <option value="ford">Ford</option>
  <option value="chrysler">Chrysler</option>
  <option value="dodge">Dodge</option>
</select>
```

Any recommendations of drop down component that is working good on android web-view?

Comment: You found anything?